# EasyBCD query for Resetting BCD

Tags: boot

I have accidently reset BCD configuration using EasyBCD. I have only one OS installed. I am afraid i wont be able to boot next time. Typing this after resetting.
I havent shutdown my pc being afraid 0xc0000098 error would come.
Please help ..what should I do?

Comment: Can you choose your operating system (I assume it is Windows) under Edit boot menu as the default or is the list complet empty?

Comment: You should under no situation use EasyBCD.  I used it once and it screwed up my own system.  In every question I have seen, by an author who had used this particular application, they also had a problem.  Boot into an Windows Recovery Environment and use the appropriate command to rebuild the BCD.

Comment: @ Wiffzack- Yes i can see list in Edit boot menu. I have Windows 7 and It has four entries for Windows 7 and first entry is checked as default.

Comment: @ Ramhound- could you please elaborate how to do that?

Comment: There are several dozen questions with detailed answers on how to rebuild the BCD for a Windows configuration.  Before I do the appropriate research to submit an answer, what research have you done, in what way are those answers not already clear?

Answer (score 0):

> I have Windows 7 and It has four entries for Windows 7 and first
>   entry is checked as default.

Do you have 4 Windows 7 installations? Seems odd. I assume you have a single Windows 7 installation.

I can suggest a reliable BCD tool which does not change anything without first getting a confirmation from the user for the selected BCD operation - [graphical bcdedit tool](https://www.boyans.net).

It works with combination of "[Dual-boot Repair tool for Windows 10 (and earlier versions)](https://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html)".

1) Download both tools. Use either tool to backup current BCD just for the record.

2) Then execute "Automatic Repair" option in Dual-boot Repair tool - this will create a new "good" boot entry for Windows 7 (or fix an existing one in BCD).

**If "Automatic Repair" finishes successfully you can reboot safely.**

The default boot entry will be the "good" boot entry.

3) Then you can delete all unnecessary boot entries to clean up BCD using Visual BCD Editor(VBCDE) if you like. VBCDE gives complete view of whole BCD and access to every BCD object and element.

Some basic knowledge of BCD structure, objects and elements would be nice to have before you manipulate BCD (delete loaders, change loader or boot manager parameters) as you can very easily make your system unbootable (BCD = Boot Configuration Data).

Advice:

ALWAYS HAVE A WINDOWS 7 RECOVERY/INSTALLATION DVD/USB READY when manipulating BCD, boot sectors, MBR, disk partitions etc.

and

the necessary operations/commands written on paper which can fix Windows 7 booting using recovery. There are mainly two alternative tool chains for fixing boot - bootrec.exe or (bootsect.exe + bcdboot.exe).

Good luck.